# How to validate regex using express-validator?

Tags: validation, express-validator

I'm trying to validate a mobile number regex using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/).

I have browsed through the docs api but couldn't find the validator function that checks a regex. Will using `regex.test()` like the following work?

```
body('mobile', 'Invalid mobile number.')
           .escape()
           .exists({checkFalsy: true})
           .isLength({min: 11, max:11})
           .regex.test(/^(\+123)\d{11}$/)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found `.matches()` validator function in [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) which is the equivalent of `regex.test()`.

```
body('mobile', 'Invalid mobile number.')
.escape()
.exists({checkFalsy: true})
.isLength({min: 11, max:11})
.matches(/^(09|\+639)\d{9}$/)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have that matches function in `createSchema`, you can add like this:

```
password:{
in:['body'],
errorMessage:"Password required",
isString:true,
matches:{options:{
source:/ain/
}},
withMessage:'Password is not valid'
}
```